# Nagios or Ubuntu Landscape free/personal for two personal servers in different houses

Tags: server, landscape, monitoring, nagios3

I have two Ubuntu (Xubuntu) 14.04 LTS servers. One at my parents' house and one at mine. Ideally I want two things:

- being able to see system information like CPU usage, memory usage and disk usage (and available updates if possible)
- getting an e-mail to my gMail account if CPU or memory usage is too high for too long, or disk space is running low, etc... (I've already configured Postfix with gMail relay so I can send email to my gMail from my machine.)

From what I have seen I have two options: Nagios or Ubuntu Landscape free/personal use and I'm wondering which would suit my needs better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landscape is certainly capable of doing the things you ask, but installing a Landscape Dedicated Server is somewhat more tricky than setting up nagios.  That said it'd look great on your resume!

Obviously Landscape will also allow you to do things like package management remotely (and have security updates applied automatically, for example).